# Android table layout no margins

Tags: android, android-animation, tablelayout

I want to create a layout with independents block on the top, Here is how i got it so far, i can't get rid of the margins and center the blocks
[image]

I can't figure out how to get the 4 blocks to arrange like that, i could make a single image out of the 4 blocks but i want to animate each one separately (intro animations).

Any ideas?

This is my LoginLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_login"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="250dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <!-- Column 1 -->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <!-- Column 2 -->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_sound"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_sound" />

            <!-- Column 3 -->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_video"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_video" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <!-- Column 1 -->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_sound"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_photo" />

            <!-- Column 2 -->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_sound"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_draw" />

            <!-- Column 3 -->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_selfierush"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:text="Connect to get started"
            android:textColor="#24b762" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEmail"
            style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Connect with email" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFb"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layers_fb_button_bg"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Connect with Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGplus"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layers_gplus_button_bg"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Connect with Google+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTwitter"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layers_twitter_button_bg"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Connect with Twitter" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does it have to use a TableLayout?  You can do this in a much smaller layout file without one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same shape without the complexity of a TableLayout. Stick to a RelativeLayout and position the views:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/yellow"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#fc0" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/yellow"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#00f" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/green"
        android:layout_above="@id/blue"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/yellow"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#0f0" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/green"
        android:layout_above="@id/blue"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#f00" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Tetris layout :)]